# what is the difference between 寒い and 寒?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

is there really a difference between the 2? Jisho (辞書?) lists さむい for 寒い & さむ.い 寒. What difference い make?

Comment: What I mean if it's not clear is if they are both pronounced the same why is い used on 1 & not the other?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are looking at [this entry](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%AF%92%20%23kanji):

[image]

The dot in さむ.い means that 寒 is pronounced さむ in the word さむい. 寒 by itself is not pronounced さむい. In fact, if you click on さむ.い in jisho, it will link you to the entry for 寒い.

You might want to look a bit more into kanji, but idea is that for most cases, you will not know the reading of the kanji until it is combined with other kanji or followed with hiragana.